Strapi cloudinary config V4: error: Error uploading to cloudinary
I am trying to add cloudinary to my strapi backend but it's not working. I have followed the documentation even changed cloudinary keys but still nothing works and i get an error when uploading an image from the media library
error: Error uploading to cloudinary:  Error: Error uploading to cloudinary: 
I have tried following up on the documentation but still nothing works
This is the error I am getting from my terminal

[2024-04-14 14:39:51.051] error: Error uploading to cloudinary:
Error: Error uploading to cloudinary:
at /home/cliff/Documents/projects/daktari-admin/node_modules/@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary/dist/index.js:47:22
at /home/cliff/Documents/projects/daktari-admin/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils/index.js:1354:14
at handle_response (/home/cliff/Documents/projects/daktari-admin/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/uploader.js:486:7)
at ClientRequest. (/home/cliff/Documents/projects/daktari-admin/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/uploader.js:603:12)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:530:35)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:488:12)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
[2024-04-14 14:39:51.052] http: POST /upload (3646 ms) 500

https://market.strapi.io/providers/@strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary

Could you please provide the complete error message you're encountering?

What is the Strapi version you are using?

@JimLAURIE  "@strapi/strapi": "4.23.0",
